# I’m installing Apache Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode yet and I can’t get datanode to start

Tags: hadoop

What is the newest stable version of Apache Hadoop?

I have been trying to install a Hadoop Cluster, but I have been encountering different problems. For example, I am installing Apache Hadoop 3.2.4 on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) machines in pseudo-distributed mode.

I can’t turn the datanode on. Why might that be? The first time I tried it, everything came on. Namenodes, secondary namenode, nodemanagers, resourcemanager, jps and datanode.

However, when I stop-all and try to start it again, I can’t get datanode to start.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdgq6.png)

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYtkr.png)

---

I am starting from scratch now. What is the newest stable version of Apache Hadoop for installation?

I have tried version 3.2.4 and 3.3.6.

Comment: The version on the website is the latest / stable... You need to tell us your specific errors if you need help beyond that

Comment: Hi, on the website the version 3.3.6 is the latest yes, but it might not be a stable version. When it comes to open source I heard is better to go 2 versions down so it is certain that is stable version without bugs. Are you sure 3.3.6 is stable?

Comment: Yes, the `docs/stable` documentation link is 3.3.6. As mentioned, please [edit] your question with your specific setup and errors... "Stable" does not imply it will work out-of-the-box with zero configuration changes.

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer Thank you for the reply. I have already started from scratch. I was having different errors. I will post if I encounter any errors. Best.

Comment: Hello @CompEng I just add it the problem I am having now, and added a picture

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer I just added the problem I am having now, and added a picture.

Comment: Look at actual process log files. Jps isn't going to help you find why things don't start

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry how to do that? I just posted a picture of a logs directory I found. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to actually open the latest log file, not just `ls` them. For example, the datanode process isn't running, so you would `cat` the files with `-datanode-` in the name. Then add the logs as text to the question, not as an image. Also, you've already accepted an answer, so please open a new one for your errors

Comment: I appreciate the help. Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76687063/i-cant-finish-apache-hadoop-installation-pseudo-distributed-mode-datanode-is-no

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hello. I got the mapreduce job to run successfully and give the output on pseudo distribruted. However it is not showing up on the Resource Manager web interface that hadoop provides on 0.0.0.0:8088. I remember it did show up when things failed. But now it is successful and it is not showing up. Do you know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Hadoop is 3.3.6, released on 23rd June 2023. You can track and submit bugs via [the issue tracker](https://hadoop.apache.org/issue_tracking.html).

Previous stable versions include 2.10 or 3.2 versions.

Comment: Hello Ambikesh, thank you so much. It is the first time I hear this. What are the bugs on Hadoop version 3.3.6 if you don-t mind me asking. Also do you have a link to download 2.7.x. I am downloading it through the command line(using wget "link").

Comment: @user3071062 All links are found through https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

Comment: 2.7 is definitely not the latest stable build (what about 2.8, 2.9, 2.10?). Why not 3.2 if 3.3 chain has bugs?

Comment: Agreed. 2.7 is not the latest build. One can definitely go for 2.10 or 3.2. These versions might work as well. Already suggested this to @user3071062.